# How to prevent or remove duplicate value(s) in a ValueListBox

Tags: java, gwt

Our gwt app uses `ValueListBox`,

```
records.setValue(model);
records.setAcceptableValues(models);
```

Where `model` is a subset of `models`. The problem I'm having is that the ValueListBox contains duplicated value. How do I prevent or remove it?

Comment: Try using this. records.setAcceptableValues(new HashSet<String>(models);  If it is a user defined object other than string etc, then you have to implement hashcode and equals.

Comment: @bgth put it as answer. Its correct. I have just done same thing.

Comment: There is just one difference between your answer and my answer. I have suggested to override this method in place of taking care every time when `setAcceptableValues()` is called.

Comment: Yes. that will also work. But by definition override is used for changing the way something behaves. Here, override will not change the way setAcceptableVales works or behaves. It will be used just for doing this particular reason(remove duplicates) which can be achieved without override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `setAcceptableValues` methods

```
@Override
public void setAcceptableValues(Collection<T> newValues) {
   super.setAcceptableValues(new HashSet<T>(newValues));
}
```

---

Sample code:

```
ValueListBox<Integer> semester = new ValueListBox<Integer>(new Renderer<Integer>() {
    public String render(Integer object) {
        String s = "";
        if (object != null) {
            s = object.toString();
        }
        return s;
    }

    public void render(Integer object, Appendable appendable) throws IOException {
        String s = render(object);
        appendable.append(s);
    }
}) {
    @Override
    public void setAcceptableValues(Collection<Integer> newValues) {
        super.setAcceptableValues(new HashSet<Integer>(newValues));
    }
};

semester.setAcceptableValues(Arrays.asList(1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 2));
semester.setValue(2);
```

---

--EDIT--

As per your last comment try this one

```
class MyModel {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public MyModel(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.id.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof MyModel) {
            return this.id.equals(((MyModel) obj).id);
        }
        return false;
    }
}

ValueListBox<MyModel> semester = new ValueListBox<MyModel>(new Renderer<MyModel>() {
    public String render(MyModel object) {
        String s = "";
        if (object != null) {
            s = object.getName();
        }
        return s;
    }

    public void render(MyModel object, Appendable appendable) throws IOException {
        String s = render(object);
        appendable.append(s);
    }
}) {
    @Override
    public void setAcceptableValues(Collection<MyModel> newValues) {
        super.setAcceptableValues(new HashSet<MyModel>(newValues));
    }
};

semester.setAcceptableValues(Arrays.asList(new MyModel("1", "a"), new MyModel("1", "a"),
        new MyModel("2", "b"), new MyModel("3", "c")));
semester.setValue(new MyModel("1", "a"));
```

Comment: Even with the override the ValueListBox is still showing up at least one duplicated value :-(

Comment: Sorry only one. How is it possible? What's the type of your model object?

Comment: Is it a POJO class? If yes then you have to override `hashCode()` and `equals()` as per `HashSet` rule.

Comment: You have to override  `hashCode()` and `equals()` to implement your logic how the objects are unique from others.

Comment: I have updated my post. Please have a look at EDIT section. I have used a POJO as model object.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the below.

```
records.setAcceptableValues(new HashSet<String>(models);
```

If it is a user defined object other than string etc, then you have to implement hashcode and equals.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method to prevent or remove duplicate options in ListBox or ValueListBox. You have to remove duplicate values before you pass them to your ValueListBox.

Comment: Actually there's no problem with the list values, there is no duplicate on it, actually when its rendered then there's the duplicate

Comment: This means you add them twice.

Comment: Yes, but my question was specific to ValueListBox problem with duplicating items.